# Update specific characters to different font with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Range `A1:C5` merged with the following text:

> Strengths ê He will be a strong person and will do well in bowling.
> Weaknesses ê He is not very smart and will need extra attention.

How can I change just the `ê` to Wingdings 2 font, so it turns into the appropriate symbol?

The following code will turn the first instance of `ê` to Wingdings 2 but not the second instance of `ê`

```
mySheet.Range("A1").Characters(WorksheetFunction.Find(Chr(234), Range("A1").Value, 1), Len(Chr(234))).font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can pass any start/ length to the [`Characters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters) object in order to update the font, you can loop through each character in the text and just do that when it matches `Chr(234)`. For example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    FontUpdate Sheet3.Range("A1"), Chr(234), "Wingdings 2"
End Sub

Sub FontUpdate(rngTarget As Range, strFind As String, strFont As String)
    Dim lngIndex As Long
   
    For lngIndex = 1 To Len(rngTarget.Value)
        If Mid(rngTarget.Value, lngIndex, Len(strFind)) = strFind Then
            rngTarget.Characters(lngIndex, Len(strFind)).Font.Name = strFont
        End If
    Next lngIndex
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you so much.